# Views filterable by current logged in user that equals Entity Reference field?

Tags: 7, views, entities

I have nodes that have a user assigned to them as a responsible party via [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference).  I would like to have a [View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) display all the nodes that the current logged in user has they that they are the responsible party of.

Would a filter that looks something like this `Content: Responsible Party (Current User)` be do able?

I have gotten this far using the [Entity Reference Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_filter) for [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views), but it doesn't give me a "Current User" option.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your entity reference field as Contextual filter in your View advanced settings and then in the section "when the filter value is not in the url" set the "Provide the default value" to "User ID from logged in user".

Comment: You're welcome! Happy to help.